# Why external keyboard does not trigger VoiceOver when a UIButton is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

When I set an UIBUtton as `.selected` using an external keyboard, VoiceOver does not realise the change, why?

Should I post `UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement, argument: argument)`?

Notice that VoiceOver is triggered if I set any UIButton as `.selected` using double tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using VoiceOver and an external keyboard, in order to select a control and run VoiceOver, you need to press `option+control+space`. Notice that blind user are aware of this combination although is not common the usage of VoiceOver and keyboard at same time.